# Load Testing on Jmeter for Multiple User Login Through mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jdbc, jmeter

I'm performing load testing on a Java application using Jmeter. I have a mysql database through which I want to fetch users and their password in order to test for login. The steps I’ve followed till now are:

1. Setup of jmeter on system and installing blazemeter plugin on chrome.
2. Recorded test script for one user login through blazemeter. Edited it to remove all HTTP GET requests so the file only had HTTP POST requests. Saved as "login.jmx.”
3. Opened login.jmx on jmeter which by default added all the required elements, such as cookie cache manager etc.
4. Added JDBC configuration to make a connection with mysql database.
5. Added JDBC connection with select statement
   SELECT name, passwd FROM t_user;
6. Added a result tree and ran my script, all the HTTP POST requests as well as the jdbc request are working and all usernames and passwords are appearing.
7. In order to dynamically change the usernames and passwords going in the HTTP POST request I added in the VARIABLE NAME field of JDBC request
   username, pass
   and saved as OBJECT.
8. Added a counter that starts from 1 and increments by 1 in order to fetch users till the table ends.
9. Then I wrote the following statement in my HTTP POST request in the parameters tab where credentials of user are sent as:
   {"username":"${_*V(username*${counter})}","password":"${_*V(pass*${counter})}"}
   However, the username and password don’t go as text instead I get the same code back as shown in the ss below:
   [i get the same variables back instead of the actual username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiSpS.png)

Could anyone guide me as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your beautiful screenshot I can see that the JDBC Request is executed **after** the HTTP Request samplers so it's absolutely normal, if you want to use the variables from the database in the HTTP Requests you need to execute it **before** anything else otherwise the variables will not be initialized and won't have their respective values.

It worth also checking that the JDBC Request really produces the variables you're looking for using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) as your `${counter}` variable is not resolved as well.

More information:

- [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

Comment: I've placed the JDBC connection and request on top of the HTTP requests, it still doesnt take values from my db. I've checked Apache Jmeter tutorials and nothing seems to be helping either. Could you guide me further?

Comment: Also, yes i previously did add a debug sampler and its giving me the list of usernames and encrypted passwords.